# Hosting in Bluehost and redirecting it to Heroku App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, bluehost

OK. So my problem basically is:

- I'm creating a website for a company that has hosting in Bluehost.
- I've made the website in Ruby on Rails and deployed it to Heroku. (https://gruposct.herokuapp.com/)
- They already had someone start the website on the past and uploaded some files in Bluehost.

I'm trying to redirect the Bluehost domain to my heroku App via the DNS Zone Editor (reference: [here](http://documentation.unbounce.com/hc/en-us/articles/203687294-Setting-Up-Your-CNAME-with-BlueHost-my-bluehost-com-)), but it always keeps displaying the files uploaded in Bluehost. ([www.gruposct.com](http://gruposct.com/))

I don't know if what I'm trying to do is either stupid or impossible. So please any suggestion would be really helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, you're hoping to redirect all traffic that was going to gruposct.com to gruposct.herokuapp.com, in which case, rather than editing the CNAME record, you'll want to follow the redirect instructions found here: https://my.bluehost.com/cgi/help/redirects

- In summary login to: 'http://www.bluehost.com/cgi-bin/cplogin'
- Click the redirects icon, in the Domains section of cPanel
- Choose what you would like the existing domain to redirect to